# Is there a way to preload all gems to increase speed of rails boot time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I seen on the page http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/01/12/a-simple-rails-boot-time-improvement/ than the rails boot time is long because Rails load all gems at start. I checked it on my project and it's true, the loading of gems take 20 seconds on 30.

I try to add `require false` at the end of a lot of gems in my Gemfile and I gain 3/4 seconds. Not a huge improvement.

I try the load time with this command :

```
time bundle exec rake environment
```

So, my question is : Is there something, like spork or something else, to preload all gems and decrease the boot time?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can use spork for preloading your development environment. there are a lot of resources on how to use it, but there are also a lot of drawbacks, that's why i usually dont use it.

Comment: I don't find any resource on this subject. Can you give a link?

Comment: i would google for spork+rails

Comment: Obviously, I already searched it. I found a lot of examples for test frameworks but not for development mode.

Comment: where but for tests would you need spork?!

Comment: I already use spork for my test. My question is for the rails load time in developement mode. For command like `bundle exec rake environment` for example. I edited my question.

Comment: afaik rake has no drb support, so i guess this won't work

Comment: Yes it doesn't work but I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Are you talking about your local dev? Start it once and forget about it.
Production? Use Unicorn, it has zero downtime on redeploy.

Comment: Yes but for coommand like `rake db:migrate`, `rails generate`, etc.. it take 30 seconds each time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Zeus` might be of some help : https://github.com/burke/zeus

Comment: It's what I'm looking for but I can't use it because there is a very restrictive requirements.